# only number validation not working for mobile device

Tags: javascript, html

<input class="" name="mobile" type="tel" id="mobile" onkeydown="isNumberKey(this) >

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    //alert(charCode);
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) ) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (charCode == 46 ) {  //this charcode is for . on desktop
        return false;
    }else if(charCode ==229){  //this charcode geeting on mobile device.
        return false;
    }else {
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

i have written above javascript validation for accepting only number for mobile input tag. it is working fine for desktop, but when i tested on mobile device it is accepting special character "." (dot). it is not going inside of  "else if(charCode ==229)" part.
i also checked with input type="number", but same issue for that also.

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: 229 is greater than 31 and 57, so the function will already have returned false.

Comment: yes, you are right. but even though it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should put your check for `charCode == 229` on top of your if-clauses.

Comment: after put on top i am geeting charcode 229 but "return false" statement not working.

Comment: but then the error lies somewhere else. the function itself is now processed correctly by this change.